# Views search terms - ignore short terms

Tags: 7, views, search

I've got a view with an exposed search terms filter. Within general search settings, the "minimum word length to index" is set to 3. The problem is that any multiple-word search with a single word that is less than the minimum invalidates the entire search. For example, I can search for "term1 term2" and get results as expected. If I search for "term1 term2 to", I get nothing (these results include the word "to", but that word is less than the minimum).

I realize I can adjust the "minimum word length to index" setting, but in this case, it seems preferable to ignore any words less than the minimum when I have a multiple-word search. Is there any way to accomplish this?

My searches have really only turned up issues with multiple terms not working at all, like [this one](https://www.drupal.org/node/1615438), or other closed issues.

FYI, I'm using Views 3.14.